# Eclipse building workspace hangs after importing existing maven project because of JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, eclipse-kepler

When running Eclipse Kepler and importing an existing Maven project, Eclipse hangs during "Building Workspace (XX%)". Switching to the Progress tab reveals a "Validating nnn"; it looks like it’s validating a directory containing JavaScript files.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- Kill Eclipse process.
- Go to project folder and edit .project file.
- Remove the following lines (it will disable failing JavaScript validator):

  ```
  <buildCommand>
    <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
  </buildCommand>
  ```
- Save file.
- Re-open Eclipse.

Comment: This was it!  Thanks much.  I'm running Mars and had this issue.

Comment: Can you explain What will this do by removing those lines? reason for removing ??

Comment: This helped me too (but I'm not sure if it was the only thing that fixed the problem).  Like @mavis, I too would like to know what's the effect of removing these lines though.

Comment: Would also like to know the implications, thank you!

Comment: remove from .project the buildCommand javascriptValidator is like uncheck the Javascript Validator in  Project / Properties / Builders

Comment: This one had me stuck.  I tried lots of my old tricks and nothing worked until this!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I tried to install Angular.js with bower in my project. I seems bower has lots of javascript files it downloaded automatically which caused my IDE to stuck in validation process for a long time. So, I solved this problem this way,

- I first installed tern.js 0.9.0.
- Then I went to the project properties, selected tern script path
  included only the path I needed for validation, My project's
  javascript folder. I excluded other path like placeholders,
  Angular.js files, Jquery files.
- I selected the Javascript from the properties again and did the same
  things in include path's source.

My IDE currently working without freezing. I took help from there. [Tern](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Performance)
I guess it can be helpful, where any IDE stuck due to lots of Javascript file.