# Disable JavaScript validation in eclipse kepler for workspace

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, eclipse-kepler

I have the problem that eclipse hangs every time i open it as it wants to do the javascript validation. Is there any possibilty to disable the javascript validation for every project in the workspace (i don't need and don't want it) without opening eclipse (as it immediately hangs.

Comment: cause there are a lot of javascript files in the projects

Comment: Hmmm , try checking out this Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547639/eclipse-building-workspace-hangs-after-importing-existing-maven-project-because

Comment: Yes that did work. Thanks a lot! Is it possible to disable it for all projects? New projects should also not use the js validation (as otherwise after the checkout of a new project eclipse hangs again).