# Build hangs in Tizen IDE 2.4

Tags: javascript, eclipse, video.js, tizen, tizen-sdk

I am using Samsung Tizen IDE 2.4.0 Rev5 for building Apps for Samsung Tizen TV(emulator - version 2.4).

I created an App which plays video using HTML5 player. 
I want to use video.js along with the HTML5 player for playing the videos. So I took it from: 
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases (Version 5.10.1)
The issue which I am facing is that when I build the project, it (the build) hangs when it tries to build video.js. This happens every time. However, if I use video.min.js (which I believe is the obfuscated version of the same file) instead of video.js, I do not see any such build issue and I am able to run the project.
The tizen SDK is build on top on eclipse, so I checked the following question:

[Eclipse building workspace hangs after importing existing maven project because of JavaScript validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547639/eclipse-building-workspace-hangs-after-importing-existing-maven-project-because)

Where similar issue was faced and the solution was to disable javascript validation. However I checked my project files and javascript validation was anyway not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with R5.  We have a product which builds fine with R3 & R4.  When we upgraded to R5, the build would hang because of the size of our 'browswerified' client library file.  When we rolled back to R4, the project built again.  Samsung support has privately confirmed to me that they can reproduce the issue with our project.

I would encourage you to log a 'Q&A 1:1' through the Seller Office (http://seller.samsungapps.com/tv/portal/main).